# Drawing the boundary between high level API and low level API

Tags: design, architecture, api-design, libraries

Assume that were developing a cross platform graphics engine. Now we have quite a lot of low level APIs to choose from (OpenGL, Vulkan, DirectX 11, DirectX 12, ...). Now because of this, we are gonna use two APIs,

1. Low level API (this is the API which the high level API uses and this is graphics API specific).
2. High level API (this is what the user works with).

Now when designing the two APIs, we must draw the boundary on what the high level API does and what the low level API does. In designing this, if the low level API does a lot of tasks. 
**Pros:**

- We don't have to deal with a lot of "glue" codes to provide an interface between the two (low level and high level) APIs because it is written with the native graphics API.
- Performance can be expected to be better as there wont be a lot of "work arounds".

**Cons:**

- The high level API cant make a lot of specific/ low level requests from the low level API because it handles most of the things on its own.
- The developers have to develop the same features for multiple graphics APIs.

On the other hand, if we allow the user to be more specific in the high level API, 
**Pros:**

- Users can optimize certain things (buffer creation, ...).
- Developers don't get to implement the same feature for every API (it can be don't in the high level API once).

**Cons:**

- A lot of glue code might be needed.
- Performance might drop as the low level API needs to work around some things.

So this brings me to my question, 
How can we draw the line between the low level and the high level APIs when developing a cross platform library, in this case a graphics engine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) You write your engine for OpenGL 4. (2) Then you write your engine for DirectX 12. (3) Then you write your engine for Vulkan. (4) Then you factor out the parts that are common, so that you don't duplicate them. (5) Realistically, you do (4) at the same time you do (2) and (3), you don't just do a wholesale copy-paste of that code.

Comment: Also I do not understand what you mean by "drawing a line". Surely the low-level API **is OpenGL** (or DirectX or Vulkan or Mantle)? So the line is already drawn for you?

Comment: @user253751 Yes but there will be some backward compatibility issues right? (OpenGL and Vulkan for example, Ray Tracing). What I mean by "low level" is, the glue code which we use to work with those graphics APIs.

Comment: Well that's your glue code. **Your** glue code. What is glue code, and what is not? You write the code, and the part that is glue code is glue code, and the part that is not is not.